# Optimizing C# code / hard coding

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

First, I want to mention that I am not a coder.  Basically, I got stuck learning C# from scratch, which I don't really mind.

Here is a little background on what my code is trying to accomplish.

I have a cascading DDL1 for database name.  When a user selects the database name,they would need to select DDL2 for the date range (which runs different queries with "some" parameters).

The query that it runs involves joining 2 tables that are from different databases (i think this is the overall issue that i'm having).

I can get the code to work, but it seems really tedious and i'm sure that hard coding is frowned upon, unless necessary.  I did a bit of research, and it looks like I would need to use dynamic SQL to parameterized the database name in a stored procedure, which I prefer not to use.

So, in summary.  For each database name, and each date range, I would need to hard code them separately.  That would be a total of 4 blocks of code for each database.  If the data all existed in 1 table, I wouldn't have this issue.

Again, I'm fairly new and pretty much a beginner.  Please let me know if its possible to optimize the code and make it more effcient, because as of right now, it looks like bad coding to me.

The code is provided below, thanks:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter Adpt;

    if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == string.Empty & DropDownList2.SelectedValue == string.Empty)
    {
    }

    if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "ytd" & DropDownList2.SelectedValue == "db1")
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select sum(column1) from table1 inner join db2.dbo.table2 on db2.dbo.table2.ID = db1.dbo.table3.id where somecolumn = @somecolumn and Date <= GetDate() AND YEAR(Date) = year(GetDate()) AND Status = @Status", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@somecolumn", DropDownList2.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "done");
            Adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(dt);
        }

    if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "yesterday" & DropDownList2.SelectedValue == "db1")
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select sum(column1) from table1 inner join db2.dbo.table2 on db2.dbo.table2.ID = db1.dbo.table3.id where somecolumn = @somecolumn and Date >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 1, GETDATE()), 0) AND Date <= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND Status = @Status", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@somecolumn", DropDownList2.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "done");
            Adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(dt);

    //if same code, different database
        {
        }

    //if same code, different database
        {
        }

    //else if same code, different database           
        {
        }

    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();

}


protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        if (DropDownList2.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            DropDownList1.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            DropDownList1.Enabled = true;
            DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to good programming is removing redundancies when possible.  If most of your code is the same or very similar figure out how to not repeat yourself.

For example a quick refactoring of your code would look something like this:

```
var selectStatement = "select sum(column1) from table1 inner join db2.dbo.table2 on db2.dbo.table2.ID = db1.dbo.table3.id where somecolumn = @somecolumn "
string whereClause;

if (DropDownList2.SelectedValue == "db1")
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "ytd")
    {
        whereClause = "and Date <= GetDate() AND YEAR(Date) = year(GetDate()) AND Status = @Status";
    }
    else if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "yesterday")
    {
        whereClause = "and Date >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 1, GETDATE()), 0) AND Date <= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND Status = @Status"
    }
}

//etc

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectStatement + whereClause, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@somecolumn", DropDownList2.SelectedValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "done");
Adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(dt);

GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

There is still more room for improvement though.  You could reorganize the whereClause so that status only appears in one place.  You should also look into using a switch statement instead of the big block of if statements.

As for the hard coding.  The status done is a bit odd.  If it is going to be 'done' always just make that part of the select statement instead of a param.  Writing inline sql like you are isn't necessarily bad.  You have your queries parameterized to avoid SQL Injection attacks which is good.

**EDIT**:
One way to go about changing the db is to use String.Format which will replace the {#} tags with the variable of that index.

```
var sourceDb = "db1";
var targetDb = "db2";
var selectStatement = string.Format("select sum(column1) from table1 inner join {0}.dbo.table2 on {0}.dbo.table2.ID = {1}.dbo.table3.id where somecolumn = @somecolumn ", targetDb, sourceDb);
```

Looking at your code again you will probably have to move assign these db variables inside your if blocks and move the selectStatement declaration towards the end.

Comment: Thanks for the help/tip. Is it possible to parameterized the database name?: inner join db2.dbo.table2 on db2.dbo.table2.ID = db1.dbo.table3.id. I only need to pass a different database name on db1. This seems to be 1 of my main issue

Comment: Uh, yea!  Thanks for the down vote to whomever did it.  All I asked was to see if it possible to optimize it.  I did my research and I din't asked for anyone to rewrite the code.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  I can't believe I did not think about using variables.  This will definitely help me out moving forward.  However, I got a question about the code you provide:string whereclause;  It says use of unassigned local variable.  Shouldn't the string variable = to something?  I did =null; just to test my code.  Thanks again!

Comment: Yes you would need to make sure it is assigned prior to using it.  My sample definitely needs some finishing touches.